# php checkbox to add songs to checkout page

Tags: php, html, psql

okay i'm tying to get checkbox thats on my table for when checked and submitted it will redirect me to the checkout.php page then display the songs that has been submitted. my code so far

table page

```
<form action="checkout.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<body>
<div id="col2">
<?php
error_reporting(~E_ALL);
  $conn = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432
  dbname=teaching user=csguest password=r3p41r3d");
  $res = pg_query ($conn, "SELECT artist, composer, genre, title, album, label, price,           description FROM music");
print'<form action="checkout.php" method="POST"><table>';
  print "<table border='1'>";
  print "<th></th><th>Artist</th><th>Composer</th><th>Genre</th><th>Title</th><th>Album</th><th>Label</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
    while($getColumn = pg_fetch_row($res))
{
print "<tr>";
print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="cart_items" value="1"></td>';
$active = isset($_POST['cart_items']) && $_POST['cart_items']  ? "1" : "0";
for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {

print "<td>" . $getColumn[$j] . "</td>";
}

            print "</tr>";
}   
print '<input type="hidden" name="name"/>';
print '</table>'
?>
```

checkout page

```
<?php 

//print_r($_POST);//print out the whole post
$cart_items = $_POST['cart_items'];

?>
```

Comment: Your form elements are outside your form tags. Place `</form>` after `?>`

Comment: okay i have done that but that didn't change anything and when i try print_r ($_POST); i just get Array ()

Comment: Try changing `name="cart_items"` to `name="cart_items[]"`

Comment: that also changed nothing :(