# How to send checkbox through form in a table

Tags: php, html, forms, xhtml, html-table

I'm trying to make a shopping basket page that will, when the check boxes are ticked, display the songs on the shopping basket page. I think I am close I just need the last bit.

Database code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(~E_ALL);
$conn = pg_connect("host=****** port=5432 
                    dbname=teaching user=csguest password=*******");

$res = pg_query ($conn, "SELECT artist, composer, genre, title, album, label, price,                description FROM music");
print "<table border='1'>";
print "<th></th><th>Artist</th><th>Composer</th><th>Genre</th><th>Title</th><th>Album</th>     <th>Label</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
while($getColumn = pg_fetch_row($res))
{
    print "<tr>";
    print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"value="<?=$getColumn?>"</td>';
    for ($column = 0; $column < pg_num_fields($res); $column++)
    {
        print "<td>" . $getColumn[$column] . "</td>";
    }

    print "</tr>";
    foreach($_POST['check item'] as $item) {
    }
}
print '</table>'
?>
```

shopping basket code.

```
<?php
//print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
        // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
        $checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
        echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
            echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
        }
        echo "<br/><b>Note :</b> <span>Similarily, You Can Also Perform CRUD Operations using These Selected    Values.</span>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you using form tags, elsewhere that is not posted? Plus, you do have short open tags set `<?=` ? If not, either do, or change to `<?php echo`

Comment: in a different div i'm using forms do you know how to fix the problem i have? a code sample would be good

Comment: Real hard to say, since you're not showing full code. Based on another question you asked, your submit button isn't named, and this one is using a conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. Is your submit button indeed named? I.e.: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`, because the other one is just `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`. Other being http://stackoverflow.com/q/27000379/

Comment: okay my code so far will submit and POST the checkboxes but only displays whats in the value but what i need is it to display the row print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"value="<?=$res?>"</td>';

Comment: Changing `<?=$res?>` to `<?php echo $res; ?>` doesn't work? Might just be that.

Comment: nope still just submits the number of checkboxes selected but not showing a row from the table :(